# Excel pasting - How to keep cell-row relationship when pasting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have information in Excel on several rows. 
I want to copy and paste selected cells and keep each cell value on that row that it was copied from. But each time I copy the values they get clustered together on rows next to each other.

I have included an image to illustrate what I want and how it actually turns out.
I select the cells in column B with the value "Banana" (B2 and B4). When I paste I want them to look like in column D (D2 and D4). But what actually happens is the result in column F (F2 and F3).

I use Excel 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is by design; when you select noncontiguous cells and copy them, Excel doesn't remember their original location.

Workarounds:

- Copy the values one at a time to the target cells.
- Copy the entire column first, then filter it to exclude all cells with "Banana" and delete the contents from every other row.
- Use formulae to check whether "Banana" is in the same cell on the other sheet, and only return a value when it is. This formula should work: `=IF(B2="Banana",B2,"")`
- Use a macro to look at all cells in column B, and duplicate the value to column D if it says "Banana"
  Sub BananaCopy()
      Const csSrc As String = "B"
      Const csTgt As String = "D"
      Const csFruit As String = "Banana"

  ```
  Dim rngFruits As Range, rngCell As Range

  Set rngFruits = Range(csSrc & 1, csSrc & Rows.Count)
  For Each rngCell In rngFruits
      If rngCell.Value = csFruit Then
          Range(csTgt & rngCell.Row).Value = csFruit
      End If
  Next rngCell
  ```

  End Sub